# WICD shows nothing

Tags: debian, xfce, networkmanager, wicd

I have xfce debian system, the WiFi card on my laptop was not detected by the default network manager however the wired connection worked perfectly. So I decided to install WICD and remove the default network manager, using the following:

```
apt-get install wicd 
apt-get remove network-manager
```

and now with WICD installed nothing is working at all, not the wired nor the wifi it just shows a blank windows (where the networks are supposed to be)

Answer (score -1):

That's probably because the wireless interface hasn't been recognized.

Go to **Wicd Network Manager** (if you can't find it type `Wicd` in Application Launcher) **> Preferences** (arrow right top corner) **> General Settings** tab.

On **Wireless Interface** write the name of your interface (usually `wlan0` but it can be something else. To find out what it is, run `iwconfig` in terminal).

- Reboot.
- Rescan, NOT from Wicd Network Manager, but from System Tray (righ click on icon).
- Wait.

If your wireless interface still hasn't been recognized perhaps it's just switched off. If you have a laptop check if there isn't a physical button to turn it on.

*If the answer was useful, click the up arrow "^"*